# How to get data from last opened tab in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I opened tab with that code:

background.js

```
...
  var newUrl = "www.qwer.com"
    chrome.tabs.create({url : newUrl})
...
```

after opened the tab I want to get all Text in tab
I try this in content_script but its work on first tab

```
document.body.innerText
```

How can get element from that tab